# Absolute positioning of display:table element

Tags: html, css

I'm traying to create text hints for input fields on focus http://jsfiddle.net/krpkm5dc/.
The first problem was how to set max-width for position: absolute element, I found the solution - display: table.

```
 <div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text">
    <div class="hint">
        Lorem ipsum
    </div>
</div>

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.hint {
    color: white;
    background: #333;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    display: none;
    max-width: 200px;
}
input:focus ~ .hint {
    display: table;    
}
```

But when I try to position it to the right I it has strange behavior

```
.hint {   
    right: 100%;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6vxye8q5/: right side does not not match the left side of the input. Why does it behave such way?

Comment: What is the strange behavior that you are seeing? Is the hint element too narrow?

Comment: Is this how you want it to look like? http://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/6vxye8q5/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you want the `.hint` element to have the same width as the input element.

In the case where you want `.hint` to appear to the left of the input field,
set the offsets to `left: -100%` and `right: 100%`.

In the case where you want `.hint` to appear to the right of the input field,
set the offsets to `right: -100%` and `left: 100%`.

To fully understand why this works, you need to read the CSS specification regarding how offsets and widths are computed for absolutely positioned elements:

**Reference:** http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width

You can also use the margin values to offset the `.hint` element either away from the input field or slightly overlapping it depending on how you want to style the layout.

To get the shrink-to-fit width for shorter hint texts, wrap the text in an element with `display: inline-table`, and adjust the `text-align` property for `.hint` accordingly.

```css
.showLeft {
  text-align: right;
}
.showRight {
  text-align: left;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
input:focus ~ .hint {
  display: block;
}
.hint {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}
.tableit {
  display: inline-table;
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
  background: #333;
}
.showLeft .hint {
  left: -100%;
  right: 100%;
}
.showRight .hint {
  text-align: right;
  right: -100%;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="showLeft">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text">
    <div class="hint">
      <div class="tableit">
        Lorem ipsum
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="showRight">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text">
    <div class="hint">
      <div class="tableit">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet. Proin gravida dolor sit amet lacus accumsan et viverra justo commodo. Proin sodales pulvinar
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wrapper with `display: inline-table` works great, thanx Marc! As for `left: -100%` and `right: 100%` I think `width: 100%` is more clear.

Comment: There are a few ways of specifying the combination of offsets, widths and margins to achieve the same result, and a width value is probably more intuitive.  Also, you could use the width value to specify the max width of the hint box, which I think was your original idea. Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Combining `display: table;` and `position: absolute;` is always a little strange. There's really no reason why it should be ([and I've logged bugs with Chrome because of it](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=437499)), it just is. Try setting your hint to `display: block;` instead. [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Skateside/6vxye8q5/1/)

Comment: Thanx, yes it does work, but only with `width` property and in this case the hint block with will not adjust to the small content. Well, I can live with that :(